# How is multiplicative form of the spectral theorem interpreted as a spectral theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

Consider the following theorem taken from [Reed & Simon's](https://www.amazon.com.br/Functional-Analysis-Methods-Mathematical-Physics-ebook/dp/B00BCRMN4G) book.

**Theorem** *[Spectral Theorem - Multiplication Operator Form]* Let $A$ be a (unbounded) self-adjoint operator on a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ with domain $D(A)$. Then there is a measure space $(M,d\mu)$ with $\mu$ finite measure, a unitary operator $U: \mathcal{H}\to L^{2}(M,d\mu)$ and a real-valued function $f$ on $M$ which is finite a.e. so that:

(a) $\psi \in D(A)$ iff $f(\cdot)(U\psi)(\cdot) \in L^{2}(M,d\mu)$

(b) If $\varphi \in U[D(A)]$, then $(UAU^{-1}\varphi)(m) = f(m)\varphi(m)$

Now, before posting my question, let me introduce some notation. With the above notation, suppose that $f$ is a real-valed measurable function on $M$ which is finite a.e. Let $T_{f}:\mathcal{D}(T_{f}) \to L^{2}(M,d\mu)$ be the multiplication operator $T_{f}(\varphi) := f\varphi$. Here, $D(T_{f})$ is the subset of $L^{2}(M,d\mu)$ of all functions $\varphi$ for which $f\varphi$ is in $L^{2}(M,d\mu)$.

On Reed & Simon's book, it is proved that $T_{f}$ is self-adjoint. Then, they state the following:

> Unless $f \in L^{\infty}(M,d\mu)$ the operator $T_{f}$ will be unbounded. Thus, we have found a large class of unbounded self-adjoint operators. In fact, we have found all of them.

The above is stated right before the mentioned theorem, so that is seems that the theorem should justify the claim.

**Question 1:** I understand the content of the above theorem but I *don't* understand how to extract from it the information that the operators $T_{f}$ represent 'all self-adjoint operators'. How does the theorem justifies Reed & Simon's claim?

**Question 2:** What is the natural interpretation of the above Theorem? Why is it called a spectral theorem? It doesn't seem to have anything about the spectrum of $A$.

Comment: An important detail worth mentioning: the function $f$ doesn't have to be a function in the usual sense – if the spectrum of $A$ is discrete, then $M = \mathbb{N}$ and $\mu$ is the counting measure. Hence, $f$ will be a sequence and $T_f$ will be a diagonal matrix on $\ell^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The spectral theorem proves that for each self-adjoint $A$, $UAU^{-1} = T_f$ for some $f$. Thus $A$ is unitarily equivalent to a multiplication operator, so in this sense multiplication operators represent all self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space.
2. Suppose $A$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix (or more precisely, a linear operator on a $1$-dimensional Hilbert space). Then $Av = \lambda v$ for a scalar $\lambda$. So we can view $f$ as a function on one-point measure space, taking the single value $\lambda$. Bumping it up, let $A$ instead be an $n \times n$ matrix. The traditional spectral theorem says $UAU^{-1} = \Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. Take $M$ to be a discrete measure space with $n$ atoms. Then diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ can be viewed as a function on $M$, taking the values $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ (the eigenvalues), composed with projections onto the $n$ orthogonal eigenspaces of $A$. In this way, the traditional spectral theorem can be seen as a discrete-measure special case of the general unbounded spectral theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Second question first. The theorem is a continuous version of the diagonalization theorem from linear algebra. If we imagine that $M$ is finite, and take functions equal to $1$ at some point $m$ and zero elsewhere as the basis then it says that any self-adjoint operator is unitarily equivalent to multiplication by a diagonal matrix, with $f(m)$ on the diagonal, i.e. $f(m)$ are its eigenvalues (spectrum). In general, $f(m)$ may represent continuous spectrum if the measure $\mu$ does not assign a positive weight to $m$, but $m$ is still in its support.

Now the first question. The theorem says that any self-adjoint operator is unitarily equivalent to some $T_f$, in other words, it *is* $T_f$ in some unitarily equivalent representation. In finite dimensional case the change of representation amounts to simply choosing a different basis. In general, one needs [rigged Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space) and generalized eigenfunctions, such as $\delta$-functions that do not belong to the original space itself, to express it in this form. The multiplicative formulation avoids such complications. Hence the claim of Reed and Simon that $T_f$, when $f$ is essentially unbounded, represent all unbounded self-adjoint operators.

Comment: Great! Very helpful indeed! Thank you!